# What's the highest order function used in practice?

Tags: functional-programming, higher-order-functions

For instance, `mask` in Haskell is of type `(((forall a . IO a -> IO a) -> IO b) -> IO b)`. What is the purpose of such a function? Any language with a notion of a higher-order function is welcome.

For purposes of exactness, include only functions which are defined in public libraries or in use in live code.

Comment: You might want to define 'order' too. For example superficially `mask` is order 0 (`IO a` is a "value" of order 0, the argument to `mask` is order 2 as it takes a function of order 1 as argument, and `mask` itself is order 3). But if you look at `IO` as being a state-passing function then everything moves up a notch.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. By order, do you mean the rank of the type or how many levels of function types are in it?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: What do you mean "`mask` is order 0" and "`mask` itself is order 3"?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I meant it's order 3.

Comment: I was vague there, I agree. I'd be happy with either rank of type or levels of function type as I couldn't decide what the one I was most interested in would be. Apologies for yanking the chain a bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okasaki exhibits a 6th order function:
 [Even Higher-Order Functions for Parsing
or
Why Would Anyone Ever Want To Use a
Sixth-Order Function?](http://www.westpoint.edu/eecs/SiteAssets/SitePages/Faculty%20Publication%20Documents/Okasaki/jfp98sixth.pdf)